# Changing vector names

Tags: r

To tidy up my data, I used following function   -

```
tolower(gsub("\\.","",names(data)))
```

to remove Capitalization and dots (.) from long vector names like `Last.Inquiry.For.Loan`

It worked and gave back: `lastinquiryforloan`. But it is not sticking. When I run `summary(data)`, I see all the old vector names. How do I make this change permanent, so that analysis is easier for me?

Comment: I think you forgot to assign the replaced values back?

Answer (score 5):

Arun is saying that you never actually replaced the old names. Try

```
names(data) <- tolower(gsub("\\.","",names(data)))
```